# How to make Vim play nice with Python 3.7 on Windows

Tags: vim, window, gvim, vim-plugins, python3

I want to use Gvim 8.1 with some plugins, but some of those mostly require Python 3.7 Fine, I found one Gvim installation ( https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer) that was compiled with Python 3.7 however that seems to work only if I put Python3.7 Embedded in the same folder where Gvim.exe is, it does not see the system wide Python3.7 installation.

The issue with that seems to be that then the Vim plugins don't recognize the "pip3 install xxxx' installs.

So how do I get Gvim to see systemwide Python 3.7 installation on Windows 10 x64?

thanks